# How to retrieve int id from query, by matching string, in android?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I tried all things: till using database query to get id but error.

Database name: quiz

Table name: dictionary

Database columns: _id, word, meaning

Problem: How to get the _id-column value of the row, where word-column matches `Abiotic` or a String `m` passed to the function `dbBackend.getQuizByWord(m);`

```
   public int getQuizByword(String m)
    {
        int originalPosition;
        Log.d("MYINT", "Here: "+m);
        String query="select * from dictionary where word ='"+m+"'";
        Cursor cursor=this.getDbConnection().rawQuery(query, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                   originalPosition = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
return originalPosition;
}
```

From where I am passing this m String:

```
String m;
    filterText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            m=s.toString();
            MainActivity.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
```

and Item Listener

```
itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // make Toast when click
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //long data=parent.getSelectedItemId
            //Log.d("MYINT", "First------------- "+data);
            //int a=dbBackend.getQuizByword(m);

            DbBackend dbBackend1 = new DbBackend(MainActivity.this);
            Log.d("MYINT", "Here: "+dbBackend1.getQuizByword(m));
            int a=position;
            Log.d("MYINT", "First------------- "+a);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Position "+a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MeaningActivity.class);
            //i.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", position);
            i.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", a);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

[Source Code Files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_auAFDyjXXPM1JOTE80NHIxWE0)

Comment: yes `cursor.getInt()` is what you need (or rather `getLong` as IDs are longs, not ints)

Comment: You're overriding `originalPosition`  every iteration of the loop

Comment: ok i knew it is an XY problem, all you need is a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, not `ArrayAdapter`, for filtering you need to setup its `FilterQueryProvider`, thats all

Answer (score 1):

1) SQL injection is bad. Fix your query.

2) You probably don't need a loop.

3) Try catch the thrown exceptions

```
public long getQuizByword(String m)
    String query="select * from dictionary where word =?";
    Cursor cursor=this.getDbConnection().rawQuery(query, new String[] { m });
    long id = -1;
    try {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (cursor!=null) cursor.close();
   } 
    return id;
}
```

If this returns -1, then nothing is found, or there's an error

I'm not sure what `getDbConnection()` is returning, but you should move this method into a SQLiteOpenHelper, and replace that with `getReadableDatabase()`

**EDIT**

Regarding whatever you're doing with an ArrayAdapter and a Filter, you'd likely rather want to use a `CursorAdapter`, and load a different `Cursor` with the filtered data into the `ListView`. Don't jump back and forth with indicies and arraylists.

Comment: Application is shutting down with error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null

Comment: @Bati it is null because you are passing `null` to `getQuizByword` method

Comment: But I am passing a word as String. This String is in the database quiz, table dictionary, column word. That is 'Abiotic'. Here, id is returning -1, everytime.

Comment: Your error seems to suggest you're passing null. Not literally `"Abiotic"`

Comment: @Bati actually why do you need at all such a method? imho it is pointless... what do you need it for?

Comment: I agree with that statement. There's rarely a good reason to look up an ID. Your method is called `getQuiz`, not `getQuizId`

Comment: But, it is required here, because in ListView ItemList, filter is done. So, it is giving the array index which gets modified. But the exact result can be achieved only when finding the id of the original array.

Comment: Is there, any other way to, retrieve the exact index in the ListView ItemList, which is connected with Array Adapter, which is connected with the database?

Comment: @Bati no, it seems to be an XY problem, what to you want to achieve actually? do you want a `ListView` filtering or what?

Comment: I am getting wrong output, due to filter, in the dictionary, because, it is sending the index to retrieve the word and meaning from the database, according to the small array formed due to filtering. Which gives wrong output. Thats why, search for id by matching string is required.

Comment: @Bati ok i knew it is an XY problem, all you need is a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, not `ArrayAdapter`, for filtering you need to setup its `FilterQueryProvider`, thats all

Comment: @pskink, can you provide some code sample for FilterQueryProvider, giving an idea, about the implementation, How to proceed?

Comment: @Bati from `runQuery` method just return a `Cursor` matching a given `constraint` (most likely by using sql `like` statement in `where` clause)